# Windows Phone 7 Ftp client

Tags: vb.net

i am developing smartphone ftp client using visual studio and using windows phone 7

i am facing some errors like

**request.Method = WebRequestMethods.ftp.ListDirectory**

Error    1    The targeted platform does not support latebinding.    C:\Users\Zaheer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PhoneApp4\PhoneApp4\MainPage.xaml.vb    36    30    PhoneApp4

**response = CType(request.GetWebResponse(), WebResponse)**
Error    2    'GetWebResponse' is not a member of 'System.Net.WebRequest'.    C:\Users\Zaheer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PhoneApp4\PhoneApp4\MainPage.xaml.vb    37    30    PhoneApp4

**Here is the complete code please help me**

```
    Dim Request As WebRequest = Nothing
    Dim Response As WebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
        Dim Port As Integer = 21
        Try
        Request = CType(WebRequest.Create(URL), WebRequest)
            Request.Method = "List"

        Request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Username, Password)
        Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
        Response = CType(Response.GetWebRequest(), WebResponse)
            reader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
            While (reader.Peek() > -1)
                RemoteSite.Items.Add(reader.ReadLine())
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("List Sucessfully.")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

For the late binding error, you need to cast the object you are trying to set to the correct data type, as WP7 doesn't support runtime evaluation of types (late-binding).

As for the error with `GetWebResponse`, the compiler is absolutely correct, `WebRequest` (or even `HttpWebRequest`) does not have a `GetWebResponse` method, perhaps you were looking for [WebRequest.GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse.aspx)?

For example:

```
response = request.GetResponse(); // where request is of type WebRequest or a derived class
```

Comment: please tell me about my problem in the form of code or provide me piece of code for Listing Remote Server Directory am using Windows Phone 7.1

Comment: This is more than enough information to go off.... If you provide a type declaration for your `response` object I may be able to help with a code example.

Comment: Simply change `Response = CType(Response.GetWebRequest(), WebResponse)` to `Response = CType(Response.GetRequest(), WebResponse)`