# Windows Phone 7 Ftp Client Error

Tags: vb.net

i am developing smartphone ftp client using visual studio and using windows phone 7

i am facing some errors like

**request.Method = WebRequestMethods.ftp.ListDirectory**
Error   1   'WebRequestMethods' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    C:\Users\Zaheer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PhoneApp4\PhoneApp4\MainPage.xaml.vb  43  30  PhoneApp4

**response = CType(request.GetWebResponse(), WebResponse)**
Error    2    'GetWebResponse' is not a member of 'System.Net.WebRequest'.    C:\Users\Zaheer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PhoneApp4\PhoneApp4\MainPage.xaml.vb    37    30    PhoneApp4

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401332/windows-phone-7-ftp-client/

Answer (score 0):

The `WebRequestMethods` and `WebRequestMethods.Ftp` classes looks to be unsupported on WP7.

As for the error with GetWebResponse, the compiler is absolutely correct, WebRequest (or even HttpWebRequest) does not have a GetWebResponse method, perhaps you were looking for WebRequest.GetResponse?